# How can I route from one component to another?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my `app.component.ts` I have this

```
import {componentOne}
import {componentTwo}

@Component({
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
)}

@RouteConfig([
{path: "/componentone", name:"ComponentOne", component:componentOne}
{path: "/componenttwo", name:"ComponentTwo", component:componentTwo}
])

testClick(){
    this.router.navigate(["ComponentTwo"]);
}
```

which will route to componentTwo fine.

However, componentOne also tries to route to componentTwo like this

```
import {componentTwo}

testClickAgain(){
    this.router.navigate(["ComponentTwo"]);
}
```

This initially appears to route to componentTwo, but after a moment it goes crazy and automatically navigates somewhere else.

How can I route to componentTwo from componentOne?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this router (v1) is deprecated.

You should use the new router (v3): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html